# make specified ip log filtering from port mirroring input with iptables

Tags: iptables, port-mirroring

I have difficult to create an iptables rule of traffic coming from a switch that is configured as port mirroring.

I checked if the traffic from my switch is sent with tcpdump -> Tcpdump detects traffic.

So, I tried several configurations with iptables to be able to detect destination IP but nothing is detected.
The problem that I have more than 2000 destinations ip to log.
Snort seems to do not answer because too many packages to install on my CF, and difficult to send to external log manager with syslog sends.

So, I wish to do with iptables.
Do you think it will be possible to do ?
If yes, please give me some syntaxes or the iptables rule.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packets not destined for "this" host are discarded before the kernel (and therefore iptables) even sees them.

You need to put the interface into promiscuous mode (this is what tcpdump does):

```
ip link set eth0 promisc on
```

Replace `eth0` with the appropriate interface for your box.

Comment: I've just test it, but the result is the same.

Iptables does not detect incoming trafic from port mirroring. Strange!

Comment: They won't traverse iptables if they aren't going anywhere via or to or from that host.  You should be using tcpdump or pcap for this.